# Trouble loading images in Java

Tags: java, rgb, bufferedimage, toolkit, loadimage

Hi I am taking a class in Java and am pretty new to programing.

I am trying to write a program asks the user to load different images and returns their RGB values in a multi dimensional array. I have the both parts working separately but I am having trouble getting the two to work together.

I load the images in one class using toolkit.getImage-

```
void imageload1 () 
    {
        fd.show();
        if(fd.getFile() == null)
        { 
            Label1.setText("Try again");
        }//end if
        else
        {
            String d = (fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile());
            Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            image1 = toolkit.getImage(d);
            canvas1.setImage(image1);
            canvas1.repaint();

            GetRGB testRGB;
            testRGB = new GetRGB();
            testRGB.setup(image1, image2);

        }//end else
    }//end imageLoad1
```

Then send the images to a different class to get the RGB values-

```
public void setup(Image image1, Image image2) 
{
    try {
          // get the BufferedImage, using the ImageIO class
          BufferedImage image = 
            ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("imag1"));
          marchThroughImage(image);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
      }

    private void marchThroughImage(BufferedImage image) {
    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();
    int [][] pixels = new int [h][w];
    int lenRows = pixels.length;
    int lenColums = pixels[0].length;
    System.out.println("width, height: " + w + ", " + h);

    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            System.out.println("x,y: " + j + ", " + i);
            int pixel = image.getRGB(j, i);
            printPixelARGB(pixel);
            pixels [i][j] = image.getRGB(j,i);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("there are "+lenRows+" rows");
            System.out.println("there are "+lenColums+" colums");
        }
    }
}

public void printPixelARGB(int pixel) {
    int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
    int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
    int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
    int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
    System.out.println("argb: " + alpha + ", " + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue);
}
```

}

This gives me a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" error. 
I figure that the problem is that it can't read the image. I'm not sure if I need to convert the image to a BufferedImage, or if I am naming it wrong, or trying to read the file wrong. 
I have tried a lot of different way to get this to work, but haven't had any luck. Any help would be great, and much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In which line you have the error? could you put the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I am having trouble with this part, from what I can tell my image needs to be converted into a BufferedImage. BufferedImage image = 
            ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("imag1"));

Answer (score 0):

From ImageIO.read javadoc's: "Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if input is null.", so the problem is produced because this.getClass().getResource("imag1") returns null. First of all, you should specify the extension for "imag1" (.png, .jpg, etc) and test it, if the problem persists check the path in which is looking for the image (as I can see from your code, it should be in the same directory as the class that contains the method "setup").

Comment: Thanks! sorry for the late reply, got caught up getting everything working. I did have some of my perimeters off and I wasn't passing things properly. Got it all working for now. Thanks for everyones help!